# how to propose new message?

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to know the procedure to propose new sensor_msgs API.

Writing new wiki page at http://www.ros.org/wiki/sensor_msgs/Reviews and send e-mail to ros-users or ros-develpers? or write question on this web page?

I'd like to propose following messages for humanoid control

6DForce.msg for 6D force sensor (I think some of PR2 robot already have 6D Force Sensor, what msg are used?)

```
Header
 stamp
 frame_id
geometry_msgs/Vector3 force
geometry_msgs/Vector3 torque    ( moment?  )
```

For ZMP.msg and COG.msg or we can use PoseStamped.msg for this purpose.

```
Header
 stamp
 frame_id
geometry_msgs/Vector3 position
float64[9] position_covariance 
geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
float64[9] orientation_covariance
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12247/how-to-propose-new-message?/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general I would contact the stack maintainer and do a review, as they will ultimately be responsible for integrating the patch.

However, in your case, we find that the message you want already exists: [geometry_msgs/WrenchStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/WrenchStamped.html). The, ZMP and COG should probably go in their own humanoid_msgs package or something similar (you can easily create this yourself).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4